# No wrap in boostrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make header contains logo and menu.

I maked row and two columns. I used booеstrap classes. When I resize window to smaller, menu jumps under logo (look at my picture). In this moment when screen width is small and menu jumps under logo I wanna make collapse menu, but I dont know how to write it to code:

[image]

My HTML code:

```
<div class="mycontainer container-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="logo col-md-4">
        <a href = "/" class = "logo"><img src="/bendikon/wp-content/themes/bendikon/images/logo.png" alt="banner"></a>    
        </div>
        <div class="header-menu col-md-8">
        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) { ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu') ); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
              <ul class="sf-menu">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="/?p=1">Sample post</a></li>
              </ul>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

you can use `flex-nowrap` like this:

```
<div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

check it here:
[Bootstrap 4.0 flex-nowrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#wrap)

Answer (score 1):

try with the class `col-xs-8` and `col-xs-4` instead of `col-md-8` and `col-md-4`. Is normal that your columns are displayed as a plain blocks if you don't tell them how behave on xs size.

Also you might want to add the class `img-responsive` to your logo img tag to limit the maximum width to 100% of the containing column.